# Avoiding asynchonous code from beign run after the test was finished

Tags: angular, jasmine

Our Jasmine test suite is becoming flakier everyday because of asynchronous code running after the test finished.

Example:

code:

```js
@Component
export class MyComponent {

  doSomething() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      somethingThatThrowsOnTest();
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

test:

```js
it('should do something', () => {
  component.doSomething(); <-- Doesnt fail because the exception isn't thrown during the test.
});
```

How do I avoid this kind of problems ?

I made a stackblitz with this issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-fail-afterall?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

It will pass all tests and then throw a error.

Comment: use promises. Dosomething doesn't need to be so obtuse

Answer (score 1):

I like using `async(done)` and waiting for promises to resolve before asserting for them.

```
  it('should do something', async(done) => {
    // given
    const { comp, el, fixture } = setup();

    // when
    fixture.detectChanges();
    comp.doSomethingAsync(); // Trigger asynchronous code
    await fixture.whenStable();
    // your assertions
    done();
  });
```

However, in your case, since you're using a `setTimeout` of 5s, you can save yourself 5s by using `fakeAsync` and `tick`. Tick does the fake passing of time.

```
  it('should do something', fakeAsync(() => {
    // given
    const { comp, el, fixture } = setup();

    // when
    fixture.detectChanges();
    comp.doSomethingAsync(); // Trigger asynchronous code
    tick(5000);              // Make 5 seconds pass instantaneously
    // your assertions
  }));
```

=============================================
Now you're saying to avoid `asynchronous` code from running after the test has completed. Maybe you can do:

```
  // wait for the promises to resolve before going to the next it test
  afterEach(async(done) => { await fixture.whenStable(); done(); });
```

If they are `setTimeout`, I would clear the timeouts in the `ngOnDestroy` so they don't haunt you in the future.